# How was this mosaic graphic of Jimi Hendrix created?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

I found this image long time ago, even if I search with the google images search I could not find the creator to ask him/her how this was created.

I do not think it was created manually. It looks like some sort of processing was done via software.

[image: Jimi Hendrix]

If you know of any software or some way to create the similar vector image from a raster image within Adobe Illustrator, please advise.

Maybe it is possible to achieve a similar result by using some image processing programming libraries, I have no idea.

Thank you

This must be the source image:

[image: original image]

Comment: There is a designer called Tsevis he does this kind of mosaics. I think he did it on Synthetic Studio Artist 3.5. I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a photo mosaic made up of patterned tiles instead of other photos. I remember this being a really popular thing to do a few years ago. A quick search came up with this link for you:

http://www.brighthub.com/multimedia/photography/articles/34691.aspx

It has a bunch of software links to do this sort of thing.

I seem to remember seeing a tutorial on pstuts or some other tutorial site. I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: I suppose you are right. Looking again, the patterned tiles look like they were taken from some CAD software... I think they were called "hatch" patterns in AutoCAD.

Comment: I think most of them are standard patterns from illustrators built in patterns.

Comment: Note that the tiles are not all the same size. The original processing ran a QuadTree algorithm to increase the resolution in tiles with lots of detail, and ran the mosaicing with smaller tiles there.

Comment: Since they are tiles, they MIGHT all be the same size, just laid out in quads. One might use some sort of **ascii art** program with tile-able glyphs...

Comment: Hi Goofy, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, semi manually, with reasonable effort. In illustrator do this:

1. Take the image you want to make mosaic of and run **Object → Object Mosaic...**

   - (optional) reduce the color depth in Photoshop before this step
   - (optional) reduce pixel size in Photoshop before this step
   - (optional) make a gradient strip on the image for easy value order selection
2. Find a suitable swatch with patterns
3. Ungroup object (and delete image from behind)
4. Start selecting colors with the magic wand tool (adjust tolerance to suitable values) and assign a appropriate swatch. (this takes a minute or two. It is pretty fast if you took the time to make the strip and have the swatches in weight order)

[image: owl]

**Image 1**: A quick test of concept. Ideally i would have needed a bit more swatches good enough for a second try at 4 minutes per job. Image courtesy to [John McClumpha](https://www.flickr.com/photos/john_mcclumpha/5055197353/). Selection strip above, delete after use.

For multiple different levels do this for 3 different grid sizes and delete some grids to reveal the one underneath. Its relatively easy to automate this, but not a big deal to do by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

[The Scriptographer community](http://scriptographer.org) has created some options to create a similar result. Scriptographer support [ends at CS5](http://scriptographer.org/news/the-future-of-scriptographer-is-paper-js/), so none of the new fancy stuff allowed.

Take a look in the **[raster scripts area](http://scriptographer.org/scripts/raster-scripts/)** and test out a few to see what you can get.