# How to do a stroke raster effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, raster

I would like to do this effect.

[image]

https://scriptographer.org/scripts/raster-scripts/stroke-raster/

Unfortunately the pug is no longer available or updated for today's versions of Adobe Illustrator.

Would you know of another way of doing it?

Hope you can help.

Steve

Comment: "by hand" is certainly another way.

Comment: Do you have access to Photoshop? It's quite simple to do there.

Comment: @ConsumeCoffee, yes I have photoshop . . .  do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: @KMSTR - would love to know how to do it by hand - and have the confidence / skill!

Comment: Have you tried? Most things are quite doable once you start.

Comment: Yes, but I can't get a consistent line and work out the 'tones' or how thick and thin the lines should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator: how to reproduce line art](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/illustrator-how-to-reproduce-line-art)

Comment: Hi @Luciano, very nearly what I need but this will only do one tone, but I think there might be 3 tones in that image giving the different stroke thickness. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in the comments you have Photoshop, you can do it pretty quickly by following this process.

1. Open your image in Photoshop
2. Image > Mode > Greyscale

[image]
[image]

3. Image > Mode > Bitmap

[image]

4. Method Use: Halftone Screen

[image]

5. Select Line and then set your frequency to a low number (the bigger
   the image, the lower it will need to be, just use a little trial and
   error to you find whats right for you). You can also adjust the
   angle here too.

[image]

...and you are done!

[image]

if you want to increase the dark & light contrast, add a Levels Adjustment layer after step 2 and play with the black & white levels. The darker the image, the thicker the black lines will be. Sometimes you may want to go a lot darker than you would in a normal image, experiment with that and then apply the halftone effect and you should get what you are looking for.

Remember to merge the levels to the image before applying the halftone.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **Tip:** If you want to vectorize this in illutrator upscale your art before doing this then you get more data to vectorize.

Comment: Hi @Consume Coffee, thanks for that.  This I can do, but I need the thickness to be quite strong with the radius as per the example.  Other wise it's very close to what I want.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @SteveDavies try making the image darker with the Levels Adjustment layer, the darker the image, the thicker the black lines will be. Sometimes you may want to go a lot darker than you would in a normal image, try that and then apply the halftone effect and you should get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**How to do semimanually in Illustrator**

This is not really all that hard. In fact, if you combine the techniques in:

- [Illustrator: how to reproduce line art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/illustrator-how-to-reproduce-line-art/67372#67372) and
- [How was this mosaic graphic of Jimi Hendrix created?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33429/how-was-this-mosaic-graphic-of-jimi-hendrix-created/53543#53543)

you get a workflow that takes a bout a few minutes to do by hand. **Tip** you may want to use divide below. Unfortunately I'm in a bit of hurry so you need to think this out on your own for the time being.

How to determine the line thickness. Well you could calculate it First linearize your gamma than just calculate that line thickness is equal to gap*(1 - intensity) But I'm sure once you have a color swatch strip above its quick and dirty to guesstimate the dot gain, by eye.

There is also other plugin vendors that have this tool. And yes Photoshop has a tool for this. You could vectorize it in illustrator.

Comment: the first link is almost what I need but I then I need ot figure out how to get the different tones.

Comment: @SteveDavies that's what the second link is about. Making cutting masks for the separate tones.