# Any way to either resize objects a long a path/using a brush or use symbols in a halftone effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, halftone

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this but i'm looking to recreate the effect in the image below.

Is there an easy way to have each object resize individually along a path or using a brush to form a path and create this halftone-ish wave effect or instead of using circles using symbols in a halftone filter/brush.

The only other way I would have to do this is manually.

[image]

Comment: Yes, just rotate the object, then make a object mosaic, assign few sizes of to patters and apply vy color, then counter rotate. See this for further [clarification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33429/how-was-this-mosaic-graphic-of-jimi-hendrix-created/53543#53543)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My **guess** is that sample was created using [Phantasm from AstuteGraphics.com](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/phantasm) -- it excels at custom halftone-like fills.

- You merely create black and white objects or a gradient-filled object

[image]

- Set the options in the plug in....

[image]

Then add additional fills or objects for the secondary color....

[image]

This equates to black areas creating larger characters and then scaling based upon grey values.

So the creation is largely in how the original greyscale artwork is set up and the plug in settings....

[image]